# OSX CoreAudioClock how to set kCAClockProperty_Name

Tags: macos, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I am using the CoreAudioClock from the AudioToolbox Framework.  I am using the 10.11 SDK.

Whenever I attempt to set the property kCAClockProperty_Name, I get an exception.  One would think that the following code should work:

```
NSString* appName = @"MyApp";
CAClockSetProperty(self.clockRef,
                   kCAClockProperty_Name,
                   sizeof(appName),
                   (__bridge const void * _Nonnull)(appName));
```

and note that the following code to retrieve the property does not crash

```
CFStringRef nameStr;
uSize = sizeof(nameStr);
err = CAClockGetProperty(self.clockRef, kCAClockProperty_Name, &uSize, &nameStr);
if(noErr != err) { NSLog(@"kCAClockProperty_Name !!!!!  error: [ %d ] !!!!!", err);
} else { NSLog(@"kCAClockProperty_Name = ( %@ )", nameStr); }
```

resulting in the following console output:

```
kCAClockProperty_Name = ( <CAClock@0x100700620> )
```

Comment: Please, add 'core-audio' tag to your question's tags. You'll improve your chance that someone who might know the answer also sees it. (-:

Comment: In your place, I would have started the elimination process by first dropping down the SDK for one _version major_, i.e. 10.10, just to make sure if the problem was perhaps introduced by a possible recent change in the API.